# how to stop background service?

Tags: android, service

I created a background service this is working fine even app is kill state.
Now i want to stop background service when screen off  and start service when screen on.

Comment: check this it will help you https://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91

Comment: Try to implement the Broadcast receiver for screen on and off functionality. Once you get an events for screen On and screen off then in receiver call  stopService (you can access this function from context).

Answer (score 0):

In method onPause() or onStop() you must write:

```
 mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext,
                 myService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following actions:

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

But do not register a receiver for these broadcasts in a manifest because that receiver will not receive these broadcasts since This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Solution For this problem, you have to create a service, which is registering a **local broadcast receiver** for these intents. If you do this way, then your app will look for screen off only when your service is running.

Use following code:

```
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, screenStateFilter);
```

**Note:** Don't forget to un-register the receiver in the Service's onDestroy:

```
unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
```

hope this works for you...